# Sorting an element according to contents of sublist?

Tags: python, sorting, sublist

For example, in python you have a list like this:

```
test = [[0, 'cde', 'efg'], [0, 'ac', 'dfg'], [0, 'ab', 'dfg'], [0, 'efg', 'cde']]
```

And you want to sort the 2nd and 3rd elements (i.e. index 1 and 2) in this list in alphabetical order, i.e. the new list:

```
test = [[0, 'cde', 'efg'], [0, 'ab', 'dfg'], [0, 'ac', 'dfg'], [0, 'efg', 'cde']]
```

How might one go about achieving this?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it like this :

```
res = test[:1] + sorted(test[1:3]) + test[3:]
```

Comment: sorry, it should be "test"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort according to 2<sup>nd</sup> and 3<sup>rd</sup> elements use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
from operator import itemgetter
test = [[0, 'cde', 'efg'], [0, 'ac', 'dfg'], [0, 'ab', 'dfg'], [0, 'efg', 'cde']]
print sorted(test, key=itemgetter(1,2))
```

*Output*

```
[[0, 'ab', 'dfg'], [0, 'ac', 'dfg'], [0, 'cde', 'efg'], [0, 'efg', 'cde']]
```

Comment: _"If you want to sort according to 2nd and 3rd elements"_ - According to the question, the OP wants to _"sort the 2nd and 3rd elements"_, not elements by theirs second and third elements.

Comment: This will not give the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

```
test = [[0, 'cde', 'efg'], [0, 'ac', 'dfg'], [0, 'ab', 'dfg'], [0, 'efg', 'cde']]
sorted(test, key = lambda x: x[1:])


In [109]: test = [[0, 'cde', 'efg'], [0, 'ac', 'dfg'], [0, 'ab', 'dfg'], [0, 'efg', 'cde']]

In [110]: sorted(test,key=lambda x: x[1:])
Out[110]: [[0, 'ab', 'dfg'], [0, 'ac', 'dfg'], [0, 'cde', 'efg'], [0, 'efg', 'cde']]
```

You can use `test.sort(key = lambda x: x[1:])` to sort the list in place an avoid creating a new list if that is preferable.